# Handle event by list of windows form controls

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, event-handling

I have one Windows Form within a lot of `ListBoxes`, and every `ListBox` have to do the same thing. I think to handle these like a list.

`OnLoad` I create the list:

```
private List<ListBox> lsts = new List<ListBox>();        
lsts.Add(lstStart);
lsts.Add(lst0);
lsts.Add(lst1);
lsts.Add(lst2);
lsts.Add(lst3);
```

How can I write the `SelectedIndexChanged` Method for all `ListBoxes` in my `List`?

Try for answer, I didn't found a tutorial for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code first to generate `SelectedIndexChanged` for all `ListBoxes`:

```
lsts.ForEach(c => c.SelectedIndexChanged += lsts_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

And:

```
private void lsts_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Use sender to find the selected ListBox 
    var selectedListBox = (ListBox)sender;
    //Do what you want with selected ListBox 
    MessageBox.Show(selectedListBox.Name);
}
```